# How do you add a view to rails such as a modified index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a rails 4 app where I used scaffold to create a scaffold called 'documents', how can I add a view called 'report1'?  What I want to do is have a modified version of index.html.erb with a different column layout.

So far I have copied index.html.erb to report1.html.erb and linked from my menu as

> link_to "R & D Request Report", "/documents/report1", :controller => "documents", :action => "index"

When I follow that link, I get

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DocumentsController#show Couldn't find
>   Document with 'id'=report1
>
> Rails.root: C:/Users/cmendla/RubymineProjects/research_library
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/controllers/documents_controller.rb:46:in `show' Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"id"=>"report1"}

I seem to be missing a basic concept as to how to hook a view to a controller.

My goal is to be able to add variations of the index as specialized reports..

Comment: You will need to update your routes file to understand that there's a new route. You'll also need a method in the controller. If you add your current routes file and controller to the question I may be able to give you specifics. (I haven't used scaffold in a long time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a route like below :

```
get '/documents/report1', to: 'documents#report1', as: 'report'
```

link should be like this:

```
link_to "R & D Request Report", report_path
```

Copy your index method and named new method as `report1`

```
def report1
  @documents = Document.all
end
```

You should read [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) first.

Comment: That did it and I see how the controllers and views are related now.

Comment: I had some issues until I realized that I had to move the route above some of the other route statements.. working now.